# Building an array from a function

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I need to run the following function on every single page of a website:

```
<?php 
foreach ($page as $key => $item) 
if ($page[$key][4] == basename(__DIR__)) 
    echo $page[$key][0] . " " . $page[$key][1] . " " . $page[$key][2] . " " . $page[$key][3] . " " . $page[$key][4];
?>
```

I would like to retrieve the strings / variables / in an array so it can be used in the page in a dynamic fashion. Something like showing below:

```
<?php 
$result = array(
'val0' => " ",      // Value from $page[$key][0]
'val1' => " ",      // Value from $page[$key][1]
'val2' => " ",      // Value from $page[$key][2]
'val3' => " ",      // Value from $page[$key][3]
'val4' => " "       // Value from $page[$key][4]
);
?>
```

I've looked for something like this everywhere. How can that be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($page as $key => $item) {
    if ($page[$key][4] == basename(__DIR__)) {
        foreach ($page[$key] as $val) {
            $result[] = $val;
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/xM4ZCIrP